# Is Ticket To Ride Asia played with stations?

Tags: ticket-to-ride, ticket-to-ride-europe, ticket-to-ride-asia

In **Ticket To Ride US Edition** there was no stations, but in **Europe Edition** there were.

When playing **Asia Edition**, do you play with/without stations or is there no set rule about them?

I couldn't spot it in  the rules so I decided to go without stations, but I just wanted to check if there was a consensus on this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Stations are specific to Europe and could potentially break (or perhaps make) games on other continents. Since Asia and other expansion maps can be played with both US and Europe base sets, the largest common denominator would be to not use stations in expansions.

I have not tried using stations for Asia or India, perhaps it could be worth a test run, but I can see discussions coming up on combinations with Mandalas for India. Asia is more traditional in style (read: more like US) and tension remains mostly because of possible blockage by other players.

Answer (score 4):

The rules actually say that stations are **not** used, right at the beginning it says:

> This game is an expansion and requires that you use the following game parts from a previous version of Ticket to Ride:
>
> - A reserve of 45 trains per team and matching Scoring Markers taken from Ticket to Ride or Ticket to Ride Europe
> - 110 Train Car Cards taken from the same or the USA 1910 expansion

Since this makes no mention of stations, you should exclude them from your game.

Answer (score -2):

I use the stations when I play Ticket to ride Asia. I think it is working good.

According to the rules I don't think you should use them, but I am not sure. I use them and I think it works good.

Comment: Wait, you use them but don't think you should?

Comment: I don't think the rules say that you should use them, but I want to use them, so I use them.